# BeautifulSoup, a dictionary from an HTML table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape table data from a website.

Here is a simple example table:

```
t = '<html><table>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> a </td> <td> 1 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> b </td> <td> 2 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> c </td> <td> 3 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> d </td> <td> 4 </td></tr>' +\
    '</table></html>'
```

Desired parse result is `{' a ': ' 1 ', ' b ': ' 2 ', ' c ': ' 3 ', ' d ' : ' 4' }`

---

This is my closest attempt so far:

```
for tr in s.findAll('tr'):
  k, v = BeautifulSoup(str(tr)).findAll('td')
  d[str(k)] = str(v)
```

Result is:

```
{'<td class="label"> a </td>': '<td> 1 </td>', '<td class="label"> d </td>': '<td> 4 </td>', '<td class="label"> b </td>': '<td> 2 </td>', '<td class="label"> c </td>': '<td> 3 </td>'}
```

I'm aware of the `text=True` parameter of `findAll()` but I'm not getting the expected results when I use it.

I'm using python 2.6 and BeautifulSoup3.

Comment: hi there - many many thanks for this great example - this is really very helpful and a great  example - it shows me how to work with basic python data structures . BTW can we apply this great mini-lession to a real world example - eg a  table on wikipedia - i love to hear from you - regards zero

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment

t = '<html><table>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> a </td> <td> 1 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> b </td> <td> 2 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> c </td> <td> 3 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> d </td> <td> 4 </td></tr>' +\
    '</table></html>'

bs = BeautifulSoup(t)

results = {}
for row in bs.findAll('tr'):
    aux = row.findAll('td')
    results[aux[0].string] = aux[1].string

print results
```

Answer (score 16):

`BeautifulSoup` and Python have evolved, so if someone comes here with newer versions:

```
Python>=3.7
BeautifulSoup>=4.7
```

Here's updated code that works:

```py
# import bs4 and create your 'soup' object

table = soup.find('table')

headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
results = [{headers[i]: cell for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td'))}
           for row in table.find_all('tr')]
```

Comment: hi there dear Martin Martin .- great:  i like this approach: at the moment i am learing python and i find it very helpful to do this with bs4: your code shows how to create a soup-object:- many many thanks for this great example - this is really very helpful and a great example - it shows me how to work with basic python data structures . BTW can we apply this great mini-lession to a real world example - eg a table on wikipedia - i love to hear from you - regards zero

Comment: Hello @zero - check out the tutorial on [Beautiful Soup: Build A Web Scraper in Python](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python) for an example that walks you through the whole scraping process on a real-world example. Hope that helps and keep learning! : )

Answer (score 8):

If you're scraping a table has an explicit "thead" and "tbody" such as:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Finished</th>
            <th>Unfinished</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td>63</td> <td>33</td> <td>2</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>69</td> <td>29</td> <td>3</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>57</td> <td>28</td> <td>1</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use the following:

```
headers = [header.text_content() for header in table.cssselect("thead tr th")]
results = [{headers[i]: cell.text_content() for i, cell in enumerate(row.cssselect("td"))} for row in table.cssselect("tbody tr")]
```

This will produce:

```
[
  {"Total": "63", "Finished": "33", "Unfinished": "2"},
  {"Total": "69", "Finished": "29", "Unfinished": "3"},
  {"Total": "57", "Finished": "28", "Unfinished": "1"}
]
```

P.S. This is using lxml.html. If you are using BeautifulSoup replace ".text_content()" with ".string" and ".cssselect" with ".findAll".

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the same approach as [mvillaress](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578965/mvillaress), but improve it a bit, using [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

t = '<html><table>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> a </td> <td> 1 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> b </td> <td> 2 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> c </td> <td> 3 </td></tr>' +\
    '<tr><td class="label"> d </td> <td> 4 </td></tr>' +\
    '</table></html>'

bs = BeautifulSoup(t)
tds = [row.findAll('td') for row in bs.findAll('tr')]
results = { td[0].string: td[1].string for td in tds }
print results
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I believe is closer to the original attempt:

```
d={}
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    key = tr.text.split()[0]
    val = tr.text.split()[1]
    d[key] = val

print(d)
```