# Parsing html table with BeautifulSoup to python dictionary

Tags: python, html, dictionary, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

This is an html code than I'm trying to parse with BeautifulSoup:

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th width="100">menu1</th>
            <td>
              <ul class="classno1" style="margin-bottom:10;">
                    <li>Some data1</li>
                    <li>Foo1<a href="/link/to/bar1">Bar1</a></li>
                    ... (amount of this tags isn't fixed)
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="100">menu2</th>
            <td>
              <ul class="classno1" style="margin-bottom:10;">
                    <li>Some data2</li>
                    <li>Foo2<a href="/link/to/bar2">Bar2</a></li>
                    <li>Foo3<a href="/link/to/bar3">Bar3</a></li>
                    <li>Some data3</li>
                    ... (amount of this tags isn't fixed too)
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

The output I would like to get is a dictionary like this:

```
DICT = {
    'menu1': ['Some data1','Foo1 Bar1'],
    'menu2': ['Some data2','Foo2 Bar2','Foo3 Bar3','Some data3'],
}
```

As I already mentioned in the code, amount of `<li>` tags is not fixed. Additionally, there could be:

menu1 and menu2

just menu1

just menu2

no menu1 and menu2 (just `<table></table>`)

so e.g. it could looks just like this:

```
<table>
          <tr>
            <th width="100">menu1</th>
            <td>
              <ul class="classno1" style="margin-bottom:10;">
                    <li>Some data1</li>
                    <li>Foo1<a href="/link/to/bar1">Bar1</a></li>
                    ... (amount of this tags isn't fixed)
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

I was trying to use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901846/beautifulsoup-a-dictionary-from-an-html-table) but with no success. I think it's because of that `<ul>` tags, I can't read proper data from table. Problem for me is also variable amount of `menus` and `<li>` tags. 
So my question is how to parse this particular table to python dictionary? 
I should mention that I already parsed some simple data with `.text` attribute of BeautifulSoup handler so it would be nice if I could just keep it as is.

```
request = c.get('http://example.com/somepage.html)
soup = bs(request.text)
```

and this is always the first table of the page, so I can get it with:

```
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = """<table>
          <tr>
            <th width="100">menu1</th>
            <td>
              <ul class="classno1" style="margin-bottom:10;">
                    <li>Some data1</li>
                    <li>Foo1<a href="/link/to/bar1">Bar1</a></li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="100">menu2</th>
            <td>
              <ul class="classno1" style="margin-bottom:10;">
                    <li>Some data2</li>
                    <li>Foo2<a href="/link/to/bar2">Bar2</a></li>
                    <li>Foo3<a href="/link/to/bar3">Bar3</a></li>
                    <li>Some data3</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>"""

import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.findAll('table')[0]

results = {}

th = table.findChildren('th')#,text=['menu1','menu2'])

for x in th:
    #print x
    results_li = []
    li = x.nextSibling.nextSibling.findChildren('li')
    for y in li:
        #print y.next
        results_li.append(y.next)
    results[x.next] = results_li

print results
```

.

```
{
    u'menu2': [u'Some data2', u'Foo2', u'Foo3', u'Some data3'], 
    u'menu1': [u'Some data1', u'Foo1']
}
```