# Convert HTML response to JSON in Python

Tags: python, html, json

I have reviewed probable solutions around HTML to JSON parsing in Python, but unable to determine the correct solution.

**Context:**

Part of a prototype: I am receiving data from a 3rd party organization using request.get() method. The response is HTML 4.0 (loose.dtd format).

**Problem Statement:**
Using Json.dumps & file.write operations, I have saved this response to a local file (expecting it to be JSON).

But the content does not parse out any of the HTML tags (e.g. `<thead>`, `<td>` etc.)

I need to convert this HTML content to JSON (Or dictionary). I want to use it as data source.

**Observations:**
I have come across few java code snippets where they tried manually parsing. Hoping there is a optimal way to meet this objective.

**Sample Response**

```
<thead>\r\n<tr>\r\n<th bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Number</th>\r\n<th
bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Volcano Name</th>\r\n<th
bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Country</th>\r\n<th bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Region</th>\r\n<th
bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Latitude</th>\r\n<th
bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Longitude</th>\r\n<th bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Elev</th>\r\n<th
bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Type</th>\r\n<th bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\">Status</th>\r\n<th
bgcolor=\"#eeeeff\"><a
href=\"\"OnClick=\"hold=window.open('/nndc/DescribeField.jsp?dataset=102557&s=77&field_name=HAZ.VOL_LOC_TSQP.TIME_ERUPT','commentsWindow','menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=620,height=425,left=5,top=50');
hold.focus(); return false;\">Last
Known<br>Eruption</a></th>\r\n\r\n</tr>\r\n</thead>

<tr>\r\n<td
valign=\"top\">0803-001</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Abu</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Japan</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Honshu-Japan</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">34.5</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">131.6</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">571</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Shield volcano</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Holocene</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Unknown</td><tr>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">1505-096</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Acamarachi</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Chile</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">Chile-N</td>\r\n<td valign=\"top\">-23.3</td>\r\n<td>
```

Comment: Could you attach some examples of the data you're getting and the output you currently have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup, a dictionary from an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901846/beautifulsoup-a-dictionary-from-an-html-table)

Comment: Are you sure it's HTML, not XML? It's pretty unusual for an API to return HTML. It's almost always either XML or JSON these days.

Comment: @Kanak, thanks for forwarding the thread. Have been researching BeautifulSoup and Scrapy but yet to determine an exact solution. The thread is helpful.

Comment: @Barmar & Xorgon, sample added to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: You're right, that's HTML. It's not really an API, it's intended to be used by AJAX to fill in a table in a web page. So you'll need to use Beautiful Soup to scrape it.