# How to parse table with a internal link by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Part of html looks like the following:

```
 <li class="level1">
<span class="index">4</span>
<span class="text"><a href="#4">Reviews</a></span>
</li>
</ol><ol><li class="level1">
<span class="index">5</span>
<span class="text"><a href="#5">Games</a></span>
</li>
```

The link href=#5 refers to the following table:

```
<table log-set-param="table_view" class="ddtable qytable"><tbody>

    <tr><th>Game_name</th><th>date</th><th>team</th><th>score</th><th>opponent</th><th>starting</th><th>play</th><th>scoring</th><th>warning</th><th>details</th><th>-</th></tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E8%8B%B1%E8%B6%85">Premier_leagure</a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">11-19 23:00</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E6%96%AF%E6%89%98%E5%85%8B%E5%9F%8E">Stoke_city</a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><b>0 - 1</b></td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E4%BC%AF%E6%81%A9%E8%8C%85%E6%96%AF">Nournemouth</a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">Yes</td><td align="center" valign="middle">68’</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">0</td><td align="center" valign="middle">-</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">-</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E8%AF%A6%E6%83%85">detail</a></td>
    </tr
```

Note that there may be links in the td cell, i.e. "Premier_leature".

I want to parse the table content into a dataframe or dictionary. How to do that?
Also, how to make sure the 'href='#5' linked to the table, and use the link href's name 'Games' as the dictionary key? Because there may be multiple tables in the page.

Edit: Follow this example:
[BeautifulSoup, a dictionary from an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901846/beautifulsoup-a-dictionary-from-an-html-table)
I got the following:

```
def extract_table():
    rets = []
    tables = soup.find('table')
    for table in tables:
        headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
        ret = [{headers[i]: cell for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td'))} for row in table.find_all('tr')]
        rets.append(ret)
        print(ret)

    return rets
```

The 'headers' was right, but the 'ret' was empty. Nothing extracted from the 'td' cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that big `round`, you can easily using `pandas.read_html()` function to read it in a `table` as per your request. and then you can convert it to `dict` using `pandas.to_dict()` function as well:

```py
import pandas as pd

table = """
<table log-set-param="table_view" class="ddtable qytable"><tbody>

    <tr><th>Game_name</th><th>date</th><th>team</th><th>score</th><th>opponent</th><th>starting</th><th>play</th><th>scoring</th><th>warning</th><th>details</th><th>-</th></tr>

    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E8%8B%B1%E8%B6%85">Premier_leagure</a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">11-19 23:00</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E6%96%AF%E6%89%98%E5%85%8B%E5%9F%8E">Stoke_city</a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><b>0 - 1</b></td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E4%BC%AF%E6%81%A9%E8%8C%85%E6%96%AF">Nournemouth</a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">Yes</td><td align="center" valign="middle">68’</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">0</td><td align="center" valign="middle">-</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">-</td><td align="center" valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="/item/%E8%AF%A6%E6%83%85">detail</a></td>
    </tr
"""
df = pd.read_html(table)[0]
print(df)

df.to_csv("Data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/ab790d8518fc88afd7d2cb27b7fda62e/data.csv)

[image]

And to convert it to `dict`:

```py
target = df.to_dict()

print(target)
```

Output:

```
{'Game_name': {0: 'Premier_leagure'}, 'date': {0: '11-19 23:00'}, 'team': {0: 'Stoke_city'}, 'score': {0: '0 - 1'}, 'opponent': {0: 'Nournemouth'}, 'starting': {0: 'Yes'}, 'play': {0: '68’'}, 'scoring': {0: 0}, 'warning': {0: '-'}, 'details': {0: '-'}, '-': {0: 'detail'}}
```

> Note: Regarding your point of `Also, how to make sure the 'href='#5' linked to the table`:

There's `2` methods:

1. to use `pandas.read_html()` function along with `attrs=` as below:

Here we used the `table` attribute.

```html
<table log-set-param="table_view" class="ddtable qytable"><tbody>
```

So :

```py
df = pd.read_html(table, attrs={'log-set-param': 'table_view', 'class': 'ddtable qytable'})[0]
```

2. second method, using your lovely `href="#5` we will use `bs4` :P

So we will locate it first and then getting the next `table` for it.

```py
element = soup.find("a", href="#5").find_next("table")

df = pd.read_html(str(element))[0]

print(df)
```

Comment: That's cool. I already I have a 'soup' object, and how to get a table object for 'pd' to use?

Comment: Pardon ! What ?

Comment: In my html, there are multiple tables. How to get the 'table' object in the read_html function?

Comment: I tried your 2nd option using 'soup.find(...)', but it only returns the first table in the html page, not the table I want. It seems the href='#5' didn't effect. The first table it encountered in the html page.

Comment: @AbigailMinNM well, **That's means you do have multiple tables with the same attribute !** , so you have to use `findAll()` and then index it using `[]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210847/discussion-between--c-and-abigail-min-nm).